# How does one secure the Istio Operator?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-operator

[The documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/operator/) says,

> Using an operator does have a security implication. With the `istioctl install` command, the operation will run in the admin user’s security context, whereas with an operator, an in-cluster pod will run the operation in its security context. To avoid a vulnerability, ensure that the operator deployment is sufficiently secured.

What should one do to secure the operator deployment in Kubernetes?